# Changing marker-color in mapbox when markerLayer loaded through loadURL function

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I'm loading a markerLayer using the Mapbox loadURL function. This works fine and I'm able to access marker properties, but what doesn't seem to work is changing the color of the markers.

```
var markerLayer = L.mapbox.markerLayer();
markerLayer.loadURL('geojson.php?lat='+lat+'&lng='+lng)
   .addTo(map);

markerLayer.on('click',function(e) {
    e.layer.unbindPopup();

    var feature = e.layer.feature;
    var info = '<h2>' + feature.properties.name + '</h2>' +
               '<p>' + feature.properties.description + '</p>';

    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = info;

    feature.properties['old-color'] = feature.properties['marker-color'];
    feature.properties['marker-color'] = '#000';

});
```

Why does this not work and how would I go about changing the color of the marker using geoJson data loaded from a URL? The [posted example](http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/change-marker-color-click/) depends on geoJson data that wasn't loaded using loadUrl. I suspect that has something to do with the reason why marker colors do not change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the properties of the feature can't automatically change the icon - you'll need to call `setIcon`, like:

`e.layer.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon(feature.properties));`